# Issues with Facebook Graph API when trying to fetch page rating. I am not getting any user specific data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am using Facebook graph api to retrieve Facebook page reviews / rating, so that I can use this reviews on a website. I am getting all details except user info like name and profile pic. I am getting reviews by users and their rating on this page.

I tried /{page-is}/ratings?fields=reviewer{name,picture},review_text. It retrieves just review_text.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Here is what it returned

"data": [
    {
      "review_text": "Thank you for Wonderful Experience!!
 I bet you won’t regret...!!!"
    },
    {
      "review_text": "The first meet makes a perception. And having just the Iguazu trip...''
    }
  ],

Note : I have removed full reviews to make it smaller.

Comment: Is it your page and are you using a page access token for that page?

Comment: @WizKid Yes it is a page of my customer where I have admin access into.

Comment: Same here. Someone knows how to get reviewer's name like it is shown in docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/managing#reviews ?
I tried to get my app validation for manage_pages believing it may be grant the missing data but can't find any info about that and can't get my app validated for now...